# Jquery slider: change values on array while slider changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a jquery slider with a maximum and minimum value

```
$("#slider").slider({
    max: 1000,
    step: 5,
    min: 100,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("Current slider value", ui.value);
        for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            // modify the price on slider change
            prices[i].price = prices[i].price + ui.value
        }
    }
})
```

Also there is an array that store prices

```
 var prices = [
    { price: 200 },
    { price: 400 },
    { price: 600 },
    { price: 800 }
];
```

And modify the `price` value on slider changes but how can i properly increase and decrease the value based on slider value change.

currently my solution only add the current slider value on change.

**EDIT**

plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/rdo7VMbKmRW6jY85yadb?p=preview

```js
var prices = [100, 200, 300, 400];

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    max: 1000,
    step: 5,
    min: 100,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.value);
      for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        prices[i] = prices[i] + ui.value
      }

      $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(prices))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] - possibly with more expected output

Comment: @mplungjan updated with plunker

Comment: when slider moves right (slider value decreases) array value should be decreasing

Comment: @mplungjan did you got my issue??

Comment: yes its always increasing while moving left it should be decreasing

Comment: Did we solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function `change` on the object slider.

```
 $("#slider").slider({
        max:1000
        step:5,
        min:100
        change:function (event,ui) {
            console.log("Current slider value",ui.value);
            for (var i=0;i<prices.length;i++){
               // modify the price on slider change
               prices[i].price = prices[i]+ui.value   
            }
        })
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD7fX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just have two arrays

```js
var prices = [100, 200, 300, 400], newPrice = [];

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    max: 1000,
    step: 5,
    min: 100,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.value);
      for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        newPrice[i] = prices[i] + ui.value
      }

      $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(newPrice))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are always increasing the array values whether you increase the slider value or decrease it.

You should test if the `ui.value` has decreased to decrease the arrays values too:

```
$(function() {
  var lastValue = 0;
  $("#slider").slider({
    max: 1000,
    step: 5,
    min: 100,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        prices[i] = prices[i] + (ui.value > lastValue) ? ui.value : -ui.value;
      }
      lastValue = ui.value;
      $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(prices))
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var prices = [100, 200, 300, 400];

$(function() {
  var lastValue = 0;
  $("#slider").slider({
    max: 1000,
    step: 5,
    min: 100,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        prices[i] = prices[i] + (ui.value > lastValue) ? ui.value : -ui.value;
      }
      lastValue = ui.value;
      $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(prices))
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Explanation:**

Store the initial value on `lastValue` variabale and on each change of the slider value:

- Check if the new value is greater than the last value, so increase the array values otherwise decrease them.
- Update the last value `lastValue = ui.value;`.

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: when value decreases it should be reset to old value

Comment: @Jabaa When the value decrease, the array values will decrease with it accordingly.